# Whatsapp is receiving immediately but sending takes about 10 minutes

Tags: wi-fi

recently i tried to send some pictures to my whatsapp status but then all of a sudden nothing wants to send anymore.

i have tried all troubleshooting measures indicated on the web but nothing seems to work. i can receive messages immediately but once i send it gives me a clock sign and then takes about 10 minutes to deliver.

i am unable to uninstall and reinstall as i am in a different country without roaming on my Sim card so i wont be able to verify my number when reinstalling..

is there a way to clear a queue or something like that so my messages can deliver instantly like it used to be, as whatsapp is my only means of communicating in the place i currently am..

Any help would be much appreciated as this is a frustrating issue

Comment: Did you try the oblivious, like restarting your phone? Please edit your question to include things you've tried